# How to make Spring read sessions from the database instead of reading them from in-memory?

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, persistence

I am trying to build a clustered web application using Spring Security and my clustered environment doesn't support sticky sessions.

Basically, I am trying to persist the sessions in the database so that if one of the application servers fails the user would still have an active session on the other app servers, because he will be redirected by a load balancer to the other app server.

I can't seem to find the solution. As far as I understood, I need to reimplement the `SessionRespository`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

P. S. I don't want to use hazelcast nor redis.

Comment: Use Spring Session and for that create a JDBC implementation of the needed interface(s).

Comment: As mentioned create JDBC implementation for it (and add it as a PR to the spring-session project). There are a couple of interfaces to implement, I suggest taking a look at the source, probably better then trying to implement your own...